# Redirecting a URL: a specific folder to sub domain

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to set a 301 redirect in .htaccess

The 'dir' is a set value so it's not any directory, but the one specified only. Here's what I have --

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com/dir$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://dir.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Are you trying to redirect from the virtual directory to an equivalent subdomain name?

Comment: No, in this instance the dir is an actual directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP_POST is not a valid choice.  You can even make this more robust, but this should limit it to the specific domain by having two conditions.  One for the host header, and the other for sub-folder.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir/$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://dir.domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you try to condition `HTTP_POST` to the complete host including the subdir. `HTTP_POST` wil only contain the host which is `www\.domain\.com` in this case.

You might do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_POST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/dir/(.*) http://dir.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Not working for me. If I visit www.domain.com/dir it remains there

Comment: It's the trailing slash behing /dir. Just use ^/dir(.*) instead.